Reading CSV File in Android using ActivityResultLauncher
I am developing an Android app and trying to understand how to read the selected file's contents using ActivityResaultLauncher. I intend to choose a CSV file stored somewhere on the device like Documents, Downloads or network-attached storage and process the file content inside the app. For example, store it on the backend server database.
I can choose the file and get its path, but I can't use it to read the file contents.
I know this type of question has been asked many times before, but I haven't found one that addresses the same problem I'm facing and uses ActivityResaultLauncher.
This is what I have tried:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button importButton;

    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),  
            new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {  
                @Override  
                public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {  
                    File csv = new File(String.valueOf(uri.getPath()));  
                    try {  
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(csv);  
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);  
                    }  
      
                    Log.d("CSV", String.valueOf(uri.getPath()));  
                }  
            });

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        importButton = findViewById(R.id.importButton);
        importButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mGetContent.launch("documents/*");  
            }  
        });
    }

I get FileNotFoundException but I assume that if the file were to be found I would get some sort of permission error. I'm not sure if that is the right approach, but I am fairly new to Android development so, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Please refer this answer.

@PremDanej Thanks for the response, but I couldn't get it working as the deprecated function startActivityForResult is used in the example.

I have done a demo that works correctly as per your needs. However due to a duplicate question unable to share the code here.
